# Email Tables, Adding Image within Table- The image moves slightly right

Tags: html, css, html-email

I am trying to add an image to a footer within an email client.  Within older Safari browsers and Outlook Mac 2011, the image moves slightly to the right of the rest of the table.

I have the border zeroed out through the HTML attribute but it didn't help.  I then attempted to zero out the border with an inline style and that didn't work.

Is there any available solutions? (I have also attached a snapshot of what my problem looks like)

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
  <td align="center"><img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/5/footer-arch.png" /></td>
 </tr>
</table>
<table bgcolor="#efecef" class="content" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
 <!-- Footer 600px wrapper -->
 <tr>
  <td>
   <!-- Social & Mobile Boxes -->
   <table class="footerboxes" width="290" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <!-- SocialBox -->
      <table align="center" width="285" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" style="border: 1px; border-color: #aaaaaa; border-style: solid;" >
       <tr>
        <td height="35">
         <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; text-transform: uppercase;">
          <strong>
           Be social.
          </strong>
         </span>
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="http://facebook.com/familydollar" target="_blank" border="0">
          <img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/fb_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
         </a>
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="http://twitter.com/myfamilydollar" target="_blank" border="0">
          <img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/twitter_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
         </a>
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="http://pinterest.com/familydollar" target="_blank" border="0">
          <img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/pin_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
         </a>
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="http://youtube.com/thefamilydollar" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/youtube_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
         </a>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <!-- MobileBox -->
      <table align="center" width="285" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" style="border: 1px; border-color: #aaaaaa; border-style: solid;">
       <tr>
        <td height="35">
         <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; text-transform: uppercase;">
          <strong>
           Go mobile.
          </strong>
         </span>
        </td>
        <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color:#636363;">
         <span>
          Text
         </span> 
         <strong  style="color:#ff0000;">
          VALUE
         </strong> 
         to 
         <strong  style="color:#ff0000;">
          28767
         </strong>
         <br>
         <span>
          Visit
         </span> 
         <a href="http://m.familydollar.com" style="text-decoration: none; color:#ff0000;">
          m.familydollar.com
         </a>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <!-- BlogBox -->
      <table align="center" width="285" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" style="border: 1px; border-color: #aaaaaa; border-style: solid;">
       <tr>
        <td height="35">
         <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; text-transform: uppercase;">
          <strong>
           Get tips.
          </strong>
         </span>
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
         <span>
          Visit
         </span> 
         <a href="http://blog.familydollar.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ff0000;">
          blog.familydollar.com
         </a>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <!-- End of Social & Mobile Boxes -->
   <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="footer">
    <tr>
     <td align="left">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
       <tr>
        <td style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
         <span style="font-style: italic;" >
          While Quantities Last. No Sales To Dealers. Some Items Not Available At All Stores. Limited Quantities On Some Items
         </span>
         <br>
         <br>
         This email was sent to %%emailaddr%% by:
         <br>
         %%Member_Busname%%
         <br>
         %%Member_Addr%%
         <br>
         %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <table cellpadding="5" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
      To ensure future delivery of email, please add 
      <a href="http://www.memberlandingpages.com/address_book/address_book_add-a.htm" alias="Add Address Book-Email Address" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ff0000;">
       familydollar@efamilydollar.com
      </a> 
      to your safe sender list or address&nbsp;book.
      <a href="http://www.memberlandingpages.com/address_book/address_book_add-a.htm" alias="Add Address Book Click Here" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #ff0000;">
       Click here for instructions.
      </a> 
      <br><br>
      We respect your right to privacy - <a href="http://email.exacttarget.com/Company/Policies/PrivacyPolicy.html?linkid=View+Privacy+Policy" alias="View Privacy Policy" style="color: #ff0000">View our policy</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center">
      <font face="verdana" size="1" color="#777777">
       <br>
       <a href="%%subscription_center_url%%" alias="Manage Subscriptions" style="color: #ff0000">Manage Subscriptions</a> | <a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile" style="color: #ff0000">Update Profile</a> | <a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" alias="Unsubscribe" style="color: #ff0000">Unsubscribe</a><br><br>
      </font>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

[image: Email footer snapshot]

Comment: What I find strange is that I took the code from above and tested it on my Email On Acid account on Outlook Mac 2011 and it was fine. This could have been something related to your <head> content. But yeah odd :/

Comment: Also I have various questions and answers on HTML email in my profile. Feel free to steal any code I've posted if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Just a heads up. Took me a bit of time to see what the issue was. Didn't realize it was the top of the footer that was out (hard to see since it's ever so slight).

Try:

```
<table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td><img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/5/footer-arch.png" width="600" height="53" style="display: block; border: 0;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I made the footer image parent table the same width as the table below it.

Also I recommend setting width and heights for ALL images and do it in the HTML. Not sure if it would have a mass of difference but always better to do things in the most basic format possible (as in: if you can do it in the HTML over the CSS then do!)

Solution 2:

Wrap both tables in a 600 width table that is centered. Then make both child tables go 100%.

Comment: Not used this before - very useful!

Comment: Yes, just be careful **not** to use css `*` global selector for example. On the other hand it could be good for `font-family` maybe.

Comment: Not sure I could bring myself to use anything with * in HTML email!

Comment: @lejimmie that you for your help, yes the issue is a "fine" one :).  What you suggested was actually my first solution.  Where this gets strange is that for some odd reason, this table will not center but float off to the far left for Outlook 2011 on Mac.  Even though it would be setup the same as the other table and the other table center's like it should, this table with the image will not center.  Of course, it works just fine with other email clients.

Comment: Hmm OK - will write more solutions in my answer

Comment: Did you by any chance redo the width and height for you images in the HTML? I strongly recommended :)

Comment: I understand that strong recommendation. What I'm trying to do is to have that arch be responsive.  What do you think of this...

`<img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/5/footer-arch.png" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px; display: block; border: 0;" />`

Comment: Even if responsive I'd still add the width and height in. Then add the media query at the top @media screen an (max-width: 600px) { img[class="footerImage"] {width:100%!important; height: auto!Important; } }

Comment: I'll give it a shot.  I'll be able to apply this solution within the next two hours.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: you can also place another nested table inside and leave image at percent. Table/td css is much better supported than img so by controlling the image with a table container, you can use the percentage and max-width hybrid approach or the full responsive media query approach with greater success.

Comment: also - can't  you just move the image into a td inside the footer table? does it have to be a completely separate table?

Comment: Thank you @Gortonington for your response.  I have the answer listed in a separate answer.

Comment: @lejimmie, you set me on the right direction in the thought process.  I have the solution in a separate answer if it would interest you.

Answer (score 0):

Building on lejimmie answer, try adding the image into the footer table and removing the cellpadding and insert it into the TD on the row below the image.

That should contain the image to same restrictions of footer below and remove possibility of misalignment.

See below for example:

```
<table bgcolor="#efecef" class="content" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
    <!-- Footer 600px wrapper -->
    <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="display:block; border-collapse:collapse;"><img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/5/footer-arch.png" style="display:block;" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="padding:10px;">
            <!-- Social & Mobile Boxes -->
            <table class="footerboxes" width="290" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- SocialBox -->
                        <table align="center" width="285" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" style="border: 1px; border-color: #aaaaaa; border-style: solid;" >
                            <tr>
                                <td height="35">
                                    <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; text-transform: uppercase;">
                                        <strong>
                                            Be social.
                                        </strong>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://facebook.com/familydollar" target="_blank" border="0">
                                        <img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/fb_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://twitter.com/myfamilydollar" target="_blank" border="0">
                                        <img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/twitter_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://pinterest.com/familydollar" target="_blank" border="0">
                                        <img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/pin_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://youtube.com/thefamilydollar" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/youtube_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- MobileBox -->
                        <table align="center" width="285" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" style="border: 1px; border-color: #aaaaaa; border-style: solid;">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="35">
                                    <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; text-transform: uppercase;">
                                        <strong>
                                            Go mobile.
                                        </strong>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color:#636363;">
                                    <span>
                                        Text
                                    </span> 
                                    <strong  style="color:#ff0000;">
                                        VALUE
                                    </strong> 
                                    to 
                                    <strong  style="color:#ff0000;">
                                        28767
                                    </strong>
                                    <br>
                                    <span>
                                        Visit
                                    </span> 
                                    <a href="http://m.familydollar.com" style="text-decoration: none; color:#ff0000;">
                                        m.familydollar.com
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <!-- BlogBox -->
                        <table align="center" width="285" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" style="border: 1px; border-color: #aaaaaa; border-style: solid;">
                            <tr>
                                <td height="35">
                                    <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; text-transform: uppercase;">
                                        <strong>
                                            Get tips.
                                        </strong>
                                    </span>
                                </td>
                                <td align="right" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
                                    <span>
                                        Visit
                                    </span> 
                                    <a href="http://blog.familydollar.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ff0000;">
                                        blog.familydollar.com
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!-- End of Social & Mobile Boxes -->
            <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="footer">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left">
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
                                    <span style="font-style: italic;" >
                                        While Quantities Last. No Sales To Dealers. Some Items Not Available At All Stores. Limited Quantities On Some Items
                                    </span>
                                    <br>
                                    <br>
                                    This email was sent to %%emailaddr%% by:
                                    <br>
                                    %%Member_Busname%%
                                    <br>
                                    %%Member_Addr%%
                                    <br>
                                    %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <table cellpadding="5" width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
                        To ensure future delivery of email, please add 
                        <a href="http://www.memberlandingpages.com/address_book/address_book_add-a.htm" alias="Add Address Book-Email Address" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ff0000;">
                            familydollar@efamilydollar.com
                        </a> 
                        to your safe sender list or address&nbsp;book.
                        <a href="http://www.memberlandingpages.com/address_book/address_book_add-a.htm" alias="Add Address Book Click Here" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #ff0000;">
                            Click here for instructions.
                        </a> 
                        <br><br>
                        We respect your right to privacy - <a href="http://email.exacttarget.com/Company/Policies/PrivacyPolicy.html?linkid=View+Privacy+Policy" alias="View Privacy Policy" style="color: #ff0000">View our policy</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center">
                        <font face="verdana" size="1" color="#777777">
                            <br>
                            <a href="%%subscription_center_url%%" alias="Manage Subscriptions" style="color: #ff0000">Manage Subscriptions</a> | <a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile" style="color: #ff0000">Update Profile</a> | <a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" alias="Unsubscribe" style="color: #ff0000">Unsubscribe</a><br><br>
                        </font>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

When @lejimmie presented a couple of solutions for me to try out, it worked perfectly but not quite for a responsive email, it did however provided an excellent guide to develop a proper solution.

For this email, a simple solution to add a media query to the header wouldn't have done the job, because we don't have control over the header code content.  Frustrating working with Exact Target sometimes on SalesForce.

This is what got the job done and so far seems to work perfectly across both mobile and desktop email clients...

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td align="center"><img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/5/footerarch.png" width="100%" style="max-width: 600px; display: block; border: 0;"></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<table bgcolor="#efecef" class="content" width="600" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center">
 <!-- Footer 600px wrapper -->
 <tr>
  <td>
   <!-- Social & Mobile Boxes -->
   <table class="footerboxes" width="290" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left">
    <tr>
     <td>
      <!-- SocialBox -->
      <table align="center" width="285" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" style="border: 1px; border-color: #aaaaaa; border-style: solid;" >
       <tr>
        <td height="35">
         <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; text-transform: uppercase;">
          <strong>
           Be social.
          </strong>
         </span>
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="http://facebook.com/familydollar" target="_blank" border="0">
          <img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/fb_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
         </a>
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="http://twitter.com/myfamilydollar" target="_blank" border="0">
          <img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/twitter_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
         </a>
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="http://pinterest.com/familydollar" target="_blank" border="0">
          <img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/pin_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
         </a>
        </td>
        <td>
         <a href="http://youtube.com/thefamilydollar" target="_blank" border="0"><img src="http://image.efamilydollar.com/lib/feea1c79706d02/m/4/youtube_icon.png" style="display: block; width: 25px; height: 25px;" border="0"/>
         </a>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <!-- MobileBox -->
      <table align="center" width="285" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" style="border: 1px; border-color: #aaaaaa; border-style: solid;">
       <tr>
        <td height="35">
         <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; text-transform: uppercase;">
          <strong>
           Go mobile.
          </strong>
         </span>
        </td>
        <td style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color:#636363;">
         <span>
          Text
         </span> 
         <strong  style="color:#ff0000;">
          VALUE
         </strong> 
         to 
         <strong  style="color:#ff0000;">
          28767
         </strong>
         <br>
         <span>
          Visit
         </span> 
         <a href="http://www.familydollar.com" style="text-decoration: none; color:#ff0000;">
          familydollar.com
         </a>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <!-- BlogBox -->
      <table align="center" width="285" bgcolor="#ffffff" cellpadding="5" style="border: 1px; border-color: #aaaaaa; border-style: solid;">
       <tr>
        <td height="35">
         <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 19px; text-transform: uppercase;">
          <strong>
           Get tips.
          </strong>
         </span>
        </td>
        <td align="right" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 13px;">
         <span>
          Visit
         </span> 
         <a href="http://blog.familydollar.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ff0000;">
          blog.familydollar.com
         </a>
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <!-- End of Social & Mobile Boxes -->
   <table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="footer">
    <tr>
     <td align="left">
      <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
       <tr>
        <td style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
         <span style="font-style: italic;" >
          While Quantities Last. No Sales To Dealers. Some Items Not Available At All Stores. Limited Quantities On Some Items
         </span>
         <br>
         <br>
         This email was sent to %%emailaddr%% by:
         <br>
         %%Member_Busname%%
         <br>
         %%Member_Addr%%
         <br>
         %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%
        </td>
       </tr>
      </table>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   <table cellpadding="5" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px;">
      To ensure future delivery of email, please add 
      <a href="http://www.memberlandingpages.com/address_book/address_book_add-a.htm" alias="Add Address Book-Email Address" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ff0000;">
       familydollar@efamilydollar.com
      </a> 
      to your safe sender list or address&nbsp;book.
      <a href="http://www.memberlandingpages.com/address_book/address_book_add-a.htm" alias="Add Address Book Click Here" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #ff0000;">
       Click here for instructions.
      </a> 
      <br><br>
      We respect your right to privacy - <a href="http://email.exacttarget.com/Company/Policies/PrivacyPolicy.html?linkid=View+Privacy+Policy" alias="View Privacy Policy" style="color: #ff0000">View our policy</a>
     </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td colspan="2" align="center">
      <font face="verdana" size="1" color="#777777">
       <br>
       <a href="%%subscription_center_url%%" alias="Manage Subscriptions" style="color: #ff0000">Manage Subscriptions</a> | <a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile" style="color: #ff0000">Update Profile</a> | <a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" alias="Unsubscribe" style="color: #ff0000">Unsubscribe</a><br><br>
      </font>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Thank you @lejimmie again, you led me to the right direction.

Comment: You are having issues with editing head style sheets in Exact Target? I think they are one of the easiest systems to edit. You should be able to easily implement styles via pastehtml email creation or you can create your own pastehtml templates to use for content block editing or content builder/canvas.

Comment: also as a tip, although it violates validation, you can put style blocks in the body of the email and it works in many clients and so far I have found little to no consequence for it. I would not use if possible to avoid, but certain ESPs have restrictions or other issues that would require this.